# How to control d3.brush (right click)

Tags: d3.js, brush

I was wondering how to have a better control of my d3.brush component.
I would like to have some extra controls on it, like:

- right click (opens a special menu, instead of regular browser one - and instead of strange brush behavior )
- been able to disable the resizable (i.e. allowing the user to only move the brush and not resizing it) brush feature (whenever I want to control it)

I've already read some older similar questions here but no luck so far.

I can already read when a right click happend on my brush area with:

```
//code from an older post 
function rightClick() { 
         if (d3.event.sourceEvent.which == 3 || d3.event.sourceEvent.button 
== 2) { //3==firefox, 2==ie 
                 return true; 
         } else { 
                 return false; 
         } 
 }
```

and here is my code that uses the rightClicl() return:

```
function brushed() {
    if(rightClick()){
        console.log("Right click : " + rightClick());
    }
    else {
        console.log("Right click <false> : " + rightClick())

                x.domain(brush.empty() ? x.domain() : brush.extent());
                if(!brush.empty()){
                  //do something and redraw it
                }
                else{ //correctiong when brush.empty() restables x.domain to general value
                  resetView();
               }
         }//end-of first else
}
```

but every time rightClick() is true, I still have my brush acting "as a regular" left-click.

Any help / insight is appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Context menu

   I'm using this [d3-context-menu](https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu) for showing context menu on svg elements.

   However the plugin can not be used on d3.brush rects directly. The right mousedown event will also trigger brush event. I tried `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, it worked.

   ```
   g.selectAll(".extent")
    .on("mousedown", function() {
        if (d3.event.button === 2) { // only enable for right click
              d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    })
    .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu));
   ```
2. Disable resize

   It seems that d3 has no explicit option for that feature.
   But you can remove the resize rects in brush group.

   ```
   // after call brush
   brushG.selectAll(“.resize”).remove();
   ```